# How to convert Vlookup to Index/match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

```
Puzzle 1 | Attempt 1 | 0
         |           |7.1
```

Suppose I have 3 columns like the above, the blank spaces have nothing in the cell. I want to get the value of 7.1

I've tried

```
VLOOKUP("Puzzle 1",A:D,1)
```

To get the value "puzzle 1" and then trying to enclose that in an `OFFSET(VLOOKUPVLAUE, 1,2,11)` which does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("Puzzle 1",A:A,0)+1)
```

would work for that.

Comment: Thanks for that @Rory.